# Why does Stream.of() give 'Cannot resolve method' error?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stream

All I am trying to do is create a stream:
`Stream stream = Stream.of("Test");`

However in IntelliJ (using Ultimate version with JDK 15), the word is red and when I hover over it, it says "Cannot resolve method 'of' in 'Stream'

I've seen all over the internet that this is one way to create a stream, but I keep getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you are having the correct import for Stream : `java.util.stream.Stream`

Comment: @RaduToader I am. This is weird...It has to be some issue with my computer maybe

Comment: The use of a raw Stream type is suspicious.  Do you still get the error if you write `Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("Test");`?

Comment: @VGR No I didn't, thank you! I'm not sure what the issue was but I tried in a different IDE and had no issues

Comment: The compiler emits a warning for a raw type.  I recommend enabling all compiler warnings, and paying attention to them.  (A raw type is a usage of a class without type parameters, even though that class normally expects one or more type parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

you probably should use

> Stream < String >  = Stream.of("Test");

instead of

> Stream stream = Stream.of("Test");